# Flutter Consumer not rebuilding UI using riverpod StateNotifierProvider

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web, riverpod

Its my 1st time using riverpod and for practice purposes, I'm making to-do app.
I'm using StateNotifierProvider and it's not updating the ListViewBuilder but updating the length of items but not showing that item. Please Guide me, Here is the SC of StateNotifier
[image]

and here is the calling method to call add method here is the SC
[image]

and here is the UI UPDATING THE NUMBERS OF items but not updating the list.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify addTask method like this.

```
void addTask(String newTask)
{
  state=[...state,TaskModel(name: newTask)];
}
```

For more information check official documentation for **StateNotifierProvider** [here](https://riverpod.dev/docs/providers/state_notifier_provider/)

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue:

```
  void addtask(String? newtask) {
final task = TaskModel(name: newtask!);
state = [...state, task];
```

}